# How to use PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory with an interface in Moshi?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, moshi

I have an interface with two concrete types as part of my model that I'd like to serialize/deserialize with Moshi. My issue is that I don't fully understand if PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory is actually meant for my use case. I've looked at the samples and a few blog posts and (if I'm understanding them correctly) all of them seem to point to the fact that your interface is supposed to have a field in the interface that allows you to determine the type. I'm working in an existing codebase and so I can't easily add a field that would allow me to figure out what type it is by some string literal.

This is where I'm at with my Moshi code and I'm seeking validation on whether or not I'm using PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory correctly. Note: I'm using java for the moshi portion of the code and for my model. My interface and it's concrete types are in kotlin

```
String json = ...;

Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder()
.add(PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(PersonInterface.java, "")
            .withSubtype(BusinessPerson.java, "occupation")
            .withSubtype(PolicePerson.java, "rank")
)
.build();
JsonAdapter<MyModel> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(MyModel.class);

MyModel myModel = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json);
```

Note: I'm using java for the moshi portion of the code and for my model. My interface and it's concrete types are in kotlin

`MyModel` is defined as the following

```
class MyModel {
    String month;
    PersonInterface person;
}
```

My interface and concrete classes in kotlin:

```
Interface PersonInterface {
    val personsName: String?
}

data class BusinessPerson(
        override val personsName: String,
        val occupation: String?
) : PersonInterface

data class PolicePerson(
    override val personsName: String,
    val rank: String?
) : PersonInterface
```

The goal is to hopefully have Moshi be able to create a

```
class MyModel {
    String month;
    BusinessPerson person;
}
```

or a

```
class MyModel {
    String month;
    PolicePerson person;
}
```

depending on whether or not the person field contains an `occupation` (which means it's of type BusinessPerson) or if it contains the field `rank` (which means it's of type PolicePerson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(PersonInterface.java, "")
    .withSubtype(BusinessPerson.java, "occupation")
    .withSubtype(PolicePerson.java, "rank")
```

means that JSON for every person is supposed to contain a key `""` and `"occupation"` or `"rank"` is the value for this key, not a key name itself as you want. So e.g. it would encode a

```
BusinessPerson("John", "CEO")
```

as

```
{"": "occupation", "personsName": "John", "occupation": "CEO"}
```

I think you'll have to write your own adapter factory for this use-case if you want to avoid a discriminator field.

Comment: Also note that the type field is in the JSON model but not the Kotlin type.

Comment: @Alexey thanks for the clarification. It seems as though I was completely misunderstanding this. From your point of view, for my use case I'd have to write my own adapter factory? Do you by any chance have any sample on how I'd write that? I really thought that PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory would be able to help here, but it seems to only help if my "type" is written out in the json.

Comment: @coltonidle I think `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory`'s source is the best starting point, actually. It's at https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/adapters/PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.java. In particular look at the `fromJson` and `toJson` methods, they are what you'll need to change.